# How to add mutiple extra tabs on product page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, product-page, product-tab

I want to display multiple tabs(inconstant number) on product page, with the code below by using layout(catalog_product_view) i am only able to add fixed amount of tabs.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">            
        <block class="AbdusSalam\AddTab\Block\ProductTabs" name="extratab"  template="AbdusSalam_AddTab::product_tabs.phtml" group="detailed_info">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Extra Tab</argument>
           </arguments>
        </block>      
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you specify your requirement in some more detail.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I want to add tabs on product page dynamically means some value(1,2,3 etc) is save in my table against a product (e.g fusion bag) and based on that value i want to display tabs on the specific product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you visit this link.

https://knowthemage.com/create-dynamic-custom-tabs-on-product-view-page/

This worked for me.